# How can i get a list of Azure VMS in my subscription showing cpus cores?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vm

I need to extract a list of vms in our subscription which also shows the cpu cores each vm has , is there a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below **PowerShell Script**, to pull the list of VM & their respective CPU Cores.

```html
Connect-AzAccount
$vms=get-azvm | select -Property Name,ResourceGroupName,Location
foreach($vm in $vms){
     $size = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name).HardwareProfile.VmSize
     $output=Get-AzVMSize -Location $vm.Location|?{$_.Name -eq $size} | select -Property Name,NumberOfCores

     Write-Output $vm.Name,$output|Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: i get get-azvm : The term 'get-azvm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function ?

Comment: Have you installed  Az modules in your machine? if not try installing the Az Modules using this cmdlet `Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser `

Comment: Get-AzVM is one of the cmdlet inside Az.Compute module here is the reference document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-7.1.0

Comment: i did that but all i get is nothing, i run the command, it executes but thats it no data

Comment: lets join this chat room & continue the discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/241719/70984312vmlist

Comment: it works if you run via portal but not via powershell on my machine

Comment: @itye1970 -  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you