# Azure Resource Graph Explorer :: list all VMs with number of cores

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, kql, azure-resource-graph

**GOAL:** I want to list all VMs in our park with the relative number of cores.

In order to do so I found this [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli#get-virtual-machine-scale-set-capacity-and-size) :

```
Resources
| where type=~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| project subscriptionId, name, location, resourceGroup, Capacity = toint(sku.capacity), Tier = sku.name
| order by Capacity desc
```

**PROBLEM:** the query return the column *Capacity* but they are all `null`

(Also solution in [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984312/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-azure-vms-in-my-subscription-showing-cpus-cores) will be accepted if they allow export to CSV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Tried with the following query:

```
vmCore=tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties.NumberOfCores)
```

But not able to get number of cores .

As i do not have them enabled in my portal to display in Json of my Virtual machine template too.

[image]

As i also Tried with `properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties`

***Graph query:***

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| project name, properties.vmId, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType,properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize,properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties
| order by ['name'] asc
```

Everything like hardware profile is resulting in output except vm size properties are empty which includes number of cores property for vmsize properties where it has to have number of cores.

[image]

Try Initially check the properties and then call the number of cores for each VM.
Below command gives VM size particularly.

Command:

```
$Myvm= Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName myrg  -Name myacctvm
```

[image]

Command:

***`$MyVmZizeProperties = Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName myrg   -VMName myacctVM`***

[image]

```
$NumberOfCores = $MyVmZizeProperties.NumberOfCores
```

[image]

```
$MyVmZizeProperties = Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName myrg   -VMName myacctVM   | Export-Csv -Path C:\vmproperties.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Reference:**  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for the effort